# Best way to pull a matching string from an array using bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

A sample array I have like below;

```
OVGARR=(ACCS ELB NOVOVG SCN MISOVG)
```

The position of the strings with *OVG can be in any index and there are more than different types of OVG strings. I want to get the value of the 1st *OVG string on the array, cut the "OVG" part of the string and assign it to a variable.

My initial solution is like below;

```
OV=`printf '%s\n' "${OVGARR[@]}" | grep -P 'OVG$' | head -1 | awk -F'OVG' '{print $1}'`
```

Though it works, is there a shorter and more efficient approach to what I would like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your original awk solution, but stripping the need to use grep and head:

```
 OV="$(awk -F 'OVG' '/OVG/ { print $1;exit }' <(printf '%s\n' "${OVGARR[@]}"))"
```

Comment: This solution do appear to be more simple than what I have. I will try this. Thank you Raman.

Answer (score 0):

Not shelling out seems to be much faster. How easy it is to read is subjective.

```
for o in "${OVGARR[@]}" ; do
    if [[ $o == *OVG ]] ; then
        OV=${o%OVG}
        break
    fi
done
```